# Prevent Superuser from deleting/removing/editing User Email in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for User signup and login purposes. Users can login using both username and email.

```
# settings.py

# Custom User Model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

# ask for either username or email during login
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
# Set Email field as required during signup
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# Set email versification necessary before creating account
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
# Don't ask for username while signing up.
# Users can later edit/change username in their profile.
# If username is not set, use email to log in.
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
# Login the user after email-confirmations
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
```

I have a users app which implements a custom User Model as shown.

```
# users/models.py

class User(AbstractUser):

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})
```

Using this setup, I am able to make user login via both email and username. However, the problem being the fact that Superuser is able to edit/remove 'email' in Django Admin. I don't want such behaviours. (An attempt to remove username however gives an "field required" error.)

My question now is,
**How to prevent the Admin from editing the user information.** i.e make 'username' and 'email' read-only fields.

Comment: Do you have a custom model admin for `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom Model admin for user and add `readonly_fields = ('email',)`

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):


fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser','role',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
    }),
)
list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
ordering = ('email',)
readonly_fields = ('email',)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, superuser is the most privileged user of the system.
It's logical that superuser has absolute access to everything.

If you want a user to have only some of the access rights, you can do that by making a new admin group and add Admins to that group. Remove the right to modify the user table for that group.